# "Import "pyautogui" could not be resolved from source" while having pyautogui installed on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyautogui

I'm having trouble right now with PyAutoGUI. I have installed it in:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages
```

but VS Code doesn't seem to recognize it.

I get this message:

> Import "pyautogui" could not be resolved from source

I've already tried reinstalling everything, set paths and verify installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python:Select Interpreter` to select the correct interpreter.

If there are multiple python versions on your machine, you need to use the one that has the ***pyautogui*** package installed.

[image]

*You can check the current interpreter path with the following code.*

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```