# "Import "pyautogui" could not be resolved from source" Error when trying to import pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm a completly begginer in python and I'm trying to use pyautogui. But whe I try to import it it gives me that error.
I'm using vscode.
I tried typing pip install pyautogui on the terminal
Anything seems to work.
Any sugestions?

Comment: That.. doesn't look like a standard Python error. Where are you seeing that error? Are you using and running your code through some IDE? That looks like VS Code's Pylance _warning_, rather than Python's standard runtime error. Please [edit] to provide more details: your code that's showing the error, and the _actual_, _exact_ error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75050024/2745495